# Smooks File Write outputTo is not writing files in windows

Tags: smooks

I have following smook config defined.[1] Here i try to process large file, so want to write the output stream to different folder and from that folder again I want to pick and process.

The issue I am  facing here is, writer is not not writing files in the folder which i mentioned.(i.e.: C:\Users\TOSH\Desktop\out) I do not see anywhere it is been writing.
Can anyone help me, what i am doing wrong here?

Note: I am  trying in windows.

[1]

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" xmlns:fl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/fixed-length-1.3.xsd" xmlns:file="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/file-routing-1.1.xsd">
         <fl:reader fields="RecordId[10]?trim,CompactedCorpName[60]?trim,FileNumber[9]?trim,CorporationName[60]?trim,FirstAddressLine1[30]?trim" skipLines="0"></fl:reader>

         <resource-config selector="csv-record">
            <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
         </resource-config>
         <file:outputStream openOnElement="csv-record" resourceName="fileSplitStream">
            <file:fileNamePattern>${.vars["csv-record"].FileNumber}.xml</file:fileNamePattern>
            <file:destinationDirectoryPattern>C:\Users\TOSH\Desktop\out</file:destinationDirectoryPattern>
            <file:highWaterMark mark="10000000"></file:highWaterMark>
         </file:outputStream>
         <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="csv-record">
            <ftl:template>/repository/resources/smooks/csv_record_as_xml.ftl</ftl:template>
            <ftl:use>
               <ftl:outputTo outputStreamResource="fileSplitStream"></ftl:outputTo>
            </ftl:use>
         </ftl:freemarker>
      </smooks-resource-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in my smooks configuration, where i map the element to csv-record, but it has to be actually 'record'.